# Difference between "Trip", "Travel", and "Journey"

Tags: word-usage, nouns

Are there any significant differences between words *trip*, *travel*, and *journey* (nouns)?

Are those interchangeable words or are there any specific expressions which uses one of them but not another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These three words can be synonyms, but have slightly different connotations.

First, **travel** is usually a verb...

> I will **travel** to Washington DC.

...but not always.  In common speech (at least as far as I am familiar), when used as a noun, it is used in its plural form:

> How were your **travels**?

Compared to the substantially equivalent sentences:

> How was your **trip**?
>   How was your **journey**?

One could also ask *How was your **travel**?*, but it this would have a more specific meaning, for instance, "How was your flight from New York to L.A.?" as opposed to "How was your entire journey, and the time you spent in L.A.?"

**Trip** and **journey** are more closely interchangeable, and vary mostly in duration, distance, and formality.

A **trip** can be a short journey.  One can take a trip to the store, but it would be unusual (except in poetic exaggeration) to take a journey to the store

A **journey** would often imply a longer (in terms of time and/or distance) trip, perhaps to multiple destinations, or with a greater sense of unknown.  A **journey** may not be fully planned out ahead of time.

A business conference to Seattle would probably be described as a *trip*, whereas a family vacation road-trip from Nebraska, through the Colorado Rockies, camping in Nevada, then stopping in Las Vegas and returning through Oklahoma and Kansas, might be described as a **journey**.

Often, in colloquial English (at least in the U.S.), **trip** is far more commonly used than **journey**, even when describing long/epic travels.

Both *trip* and *journey* can also be verbs, but when used as verbs they are not interchangeable.  **To journey** is to engage in the act of journeying:

> We **journeyed** to the Grand Canyon.

However **to trip** is to cause someone to stumble or lose their balance.

> She **tripped** the thief with her cane.
>   I **tripped** over the dog.

To **[trip up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trip+up)** has the additional connotation of causing someone to blunder:

> The reporter **tripped up** the senator.

There are also some additional cases where **trip** and **journey** cannot be interchanged in some common expressions:

- A [guilt trip](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guilt+trip)
- A high brought on by recreational drugs can be called a "trip."
- [Trippy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trippy) -- slang; reminiscent of the "trip" (high) brought on by recreational drugs; especially LSD

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any significant differences...?

Yes, there are. The context defines. I would suggest the following rule of thumb:

- Simply as a *process* of going from one place to another — use **travel**;

> Travel by air nowadays is cheaper than before.

- *Short* journey or *business* journey, *usually with a specific place denoted*, also when the *process* of going is more important than the destination — use **trip**;

> If your time permits, take a boat trip to the Samui island.
>   After receiving an annual bonus, I went on a trip to Thailand.
>   I'm often away from the office on business trips.

- *Long distance* or short but *regular* one — use **journey**;

> Did you have a good journey?
>   On my journey to work, I listen for music;

- Going to several places in a sequence, or going with an organized group — use **tour**;

> I went on a tour of France.

- A long distance on ship or space  — use **voyage** or **cruise**;

> His voyage around the world took three years.
>   A voyage through space.

Comment: "I listen for lessons of Chinese?" This sounds awkward to me; Do you mean that you listen to Chinese lessons (on CD?) on your daily commute? As written, to me, it sounds as though you have your car window rolled down, and are listening for signs that there may be Chinese lessons going on in the neighborhood as you pass...

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks, I have removed a controversial phrase. Yes, I meant, audio lessons.

Answer (score 2):

There are small differences between these words. For one, *travel* is more commonly used as a verb than a noun. You won't really hear someone say "I'm going on a *travel*", but you'll often hear people say "I'm going on a *trip*"

As for *trip* and *journey*, *trip* usually refers to a small casual outing that can be anywhere from a few days to a few weeks. *Journey*, however, has a more epic and grandiose connotation associated with it. These may span several months and thousands of miles. Historically, *journeys* occurred more often when there weren't modern forms of travel and one had to walk from one side of the continent to another.

Take for example "Journey to the West", a popular work in Asian cultures about traveling to another continent to obtain the scriptures. This *journey* was long and epic, and had multiple adventures within in. As such, *journey* is less used in modern day, but you may see it more in works of fiction.